# Laravel 5.1 localization exception

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-5.1

My laravel localization works fine with one exception. Right now I have 2 locales, EN and CS. When EN is on, everything works, but when is active CS then there occurs an error:

`Unable to choose a translation for "Před 5 měsícem|Před 5 měsíci" with locale "cs" for value "5". Double check that this translation has the correct plural options.`

Interesting is when I comment out this translation in EN locale and run web with locale EN and fallback locale CS it works perfectly.

EN: `:month month ago|:month months ago`

CS: `Před :month měsícem|Před :month měsíci`

And here is how it's called: `Lang::choice('site/post.time-hour', $interval->h, ['hour' => $interval->h]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because CS expects 3 plural forms (n==1, n>=2 && n<=4, n > 4). Try to add a third form to your translation.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but i still don't know, why one translation worked fine, but the other one no...